# BGW320/TP-Link AX10 Port Forward Not Working

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, dmz

I have a TP-Link AX10 router behind a BGW320 router (set in IP passthrough mode) to the AX10. The AX10 should be receiving all external input with this configuration, but whenever I port forward / "DMZ" on the AX10 to any port on my main server (ex. 80) and try to connect to the public IP address provided by the BGW320 to the AX10, it does not work.

I have been scratching my head at this for days and cannot figure out why it is not working.
The last configuration that had worked was the server directly hooked up (with IP passthrough) to the BGW320, however, this is no longer possible and the BGW320 will not forward or passthrough to any non-Ethernet connected devices (which I cannot do at this time.)

Is there anyway to alleviate this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.